Primes $p$ such that $p^2|(p-1)!+1$
I was working on a NT problem which boiled down to:
$$\textbf{Are there infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p^2$ does not divide $(p-1)!+1$?}$$
I know there are some primes like $p=5$ for which $p^2|(p-1)!+1$, but can we prove the statement as given above?

See Wilson prime.

Michael Penn just had a video about this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPol0Cbg2YA

yes thank you I had no idea about the wilson primes
